# What is the right way to redirect all traffic to HTTPS?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, ssl, https

## What I want to do

I manage a website on a hosting service that recently enabled the option to activate a free SSL certificate. I want to redirect all my traffic to the HTTPS version, and make it so that the plain HTTP version won't be available anymore.

## What I have tried

I have enabled the SSL certificate on the control panel, and tried to follow the procedure explained by the hosting service, that basically consists in adding some code to the `.htaccess` file, namely this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

My current `.htaccess` is already populated by the entries by Wordpress itself and a couple of plugins, W3 Total Cache and Wordfence Security ([here is a link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6Dt3cP49), sorry but I couldn't get it properly formatted here).

I have appended the code from the hosting company *to the end of the file*, but it didn't work properly and as a result the webpages were badly rendered and the URL itself was modified with random code. I don't know if it was a redirect loop, a conflict with the minification of W3TC, or a combination of both.
What I can guess after a bit of code review is that in the the `.htaccess` file there are various entries with the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` condition, that probably generate conflicts.

## What I need to know

1. How can I solve this problem with the `.htaccess` file in order to have a *working* HTTPS only website?
2. In the Wordpress admin area, in `Settings > General`, should I change the addresses from `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`? And it should be done before or after modifying `.htaccess`?
3. Is it necessary to both modify `.htaccess` and the addresses, or they do the same thing and I should apply only one of these things?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the cache and adding then updating the `.htaccess` file? your `.htaccess` already has rules for SSL. The cache may be affecting your HTML output already.

Comment: Yes, the file already has some rewrite rules, but I'm non (yet) expert enough to tell which ones affect the secure redirection; could you please point me which lines affect this? Does this mean that I only need to update the URL's in the settings page?

Comment: Ok, I did some tests: just changing the URLs in the settings page is not sufficient for a proper redirect, the plain HTTP version is still accessible; I've tried to enable the code from your answer while disabling the code from W3TC plugin, and this configuration works; obviously this is not feasible, I still need W3TC to be enabled, but at least now I can determine that this is a conflict with that plugin.

Comment: I suggest you delete your cache, update the `.htaccess` and then enable the cache. Try removing the code between lines 163 to 181 in your `.htaccess` (the code in the pastebin), and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Number 1**

If you want your website to be ONLY accessible through HTTPS, you will want to add this piece of code to your `.htaccess` file, replacing your domain's name:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will redirect any visits from non-SSL to SSL version of your website.

**Number 2**

Yes, you need to change the values of your `Website Address` and `Site Address` in the admin panel to HTTPS. It is better to do it before editing the `.htaccess` file, since after editing the `.htaccess` all traffics will be redirected to HTTPS while your website's URL is in HTTP. Also make sure your scripts, styles and images are accessible over SSL to prevent rendering issues.

**Number 3**

Yes. The .`htaccess` will redirect traffic from HTTP to HTTPS, while your `Site Address` declares that your primary domain is using HTTPS.

If you see any conflicts in the `.htaccess` file, the best practice is to copy it entirely to pastebin, and update the question with the link. I will try and see if there is a line causing any conflict in your `.htaccess` file.